# How to merge two data frame by column names python

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have two data frame, one looks like this (shape: 12553*83):

```
    A12D        A131          A12B ...
0   1.096131    2.609943    -0.659828
1   1.111370    2.650422    -0.648742
```

...

Another looks like this (shape: 1*105)

```
            A12B        A0CM        A18V...
PAM50 mRNA  Basal-like  Basal-like  Basal-like
```

I want inner merge two table by same column name. Something like:

```
            A12D        A131          A12B ...
PAM50 mRNA  Basal-like  Basal-like  Basal-like
1           1.096131    2.609943    -0.659828
2           1.111370    2.650422    -0.648742
```

Since both two table are large, column names are not completely shown. Another problem is that column names may be duplicate. I have searched serval merge methods, most of them are just merge by column value. So what can I do in this case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ``pd.concat([df2, df1])`` ?

Comment: `list(df)` will give you all column names

Comment: Thanks for the help! I know how to get column names, but I don't know how to merge two table with only those column names appears in both tables. And when I try "pd.concat([df2, df1])", it then returns "Plan shapes are not aligned".

Answer (score 2):

As @sushanth noted, use `pd.concat()` -- with `join='inner'`. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 
                    'b': [4, 5, 6], 
                    'c': [7, 8, 9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [11, 12, 13], 
                    'c': [14, 15, 16], 
                    'd': [17, 18, 19]})
t = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, join='inner')
print(t)

    b   c
0   4   7
1   5   8
2   6   9
0  11  14
1  12  15
2  13  16
```

More info here:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: Well thanks to your help! But when I try this on my data, it returns "ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned". I guess this may because here are some duplicate column names so I try the code "merged = pd.concat([cov1,pro_filled_knn_name],axis="columns")" but then the results are all NA... thanks anyway!

Comment: One way to find out if you have duplicate column names is `df.columns.is_unique` -- and you can find names of duplicates with `df.columns.value_counts()`

Answer (score 0):

Okay problems solved! Thanks to everyone's kind help! I first removed duplicate columns, then concated two tables. Like

```
df1 = df1.loc[:,~df1.columns.duplicated()]

merged = pd.concat([df1,df2],join='inner')
```